# Unity keeps crashing after I have implemeted code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

not exactly sure why. basically what I wanted to do is create a bullet hell game. so I would send a clone of a bullet to the gun, and then the gun would shoot the bullet depending on what direction it was facing. here is the code I used it is in c#. Edit: it crashes when I run the game.

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bulletcontrol1 : MonoBehaviour
{





    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Countinggggg());
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Shoot()
    {


            Debug.Log("clone");
            GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("Picture1") as GameObject;
            GameObject direction = GameObject.Find("b");
            GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(-23.25f, 8.75f, 1.494792f);
            while (go.transform.position.x > -10)
            {
                Debug.Log("moving");
                go.transform.position = new Vector3(go.transform.position.x + Mathf.Sin(direction.transform.rotation.z) * 5, go.transform.position.y + Mathf.Cos(direction.transform.rotation.z) * 5, go.transform.position.z);
            }



    }

    IEnumerator Countinggggg()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Shoot();
        Debug.Log("Bang");
    }
}```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Is there an error?

Comment: no the program freezes and then closes

Comment: Does the while loop ever exit?

Comment: ok I did some testing and it is a problem with the really long command that is supposed to move the clone in a specific direction

Comment: Hey @CooCoo333. Could you please update the question or write an answer post with what your answer was. Thanks.

Comment: oh at the time I didn't figure out just narrowed the scope of the problem but now I have figured out a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what was wrong, but I changed the while loop to a for loop, and then noticed how the bullet did all it's moves at once: so I assume something with the while loop not ending and the bullet moving infinite spaces all at once caused it.

so I put in a a WaitForSeconds to slow it down, here is the code now

```
 IEnumerator Shoot()
    {


            Debug.Log("clone");
            GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("Picture1") as GameObject;
            GameObject direction = GameObject.Find("b");
            GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(-10.13f, 3.52f, 1.494792f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("moving");
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(go.transform.position.x + Mathf.Sin(direction.transform.rotation.z) * -0.1f, go.transform.position.y + Mathf.Cos(direction.transform.rotation.z) * -0.1f, go.transform.position.z);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
```